# Can four points be a square if they are the same points

Tags: geometry

My coworkers and I have been doing code golf between ourselves, and this week we're trying to calculate whether four points form a square. Now, we realized we had all missed an edge case, which is given four of the exact same points, should that be a square or not.

One coworker says yes, as all the sides are the same length, the angles are the proper dot product, etc.

Some of us say no, because there is no area, 0 is not a length, the diagonals are not sqrt(2) times longer than the sides, etc.

Comment: I suppose that's a degenerate square. Maybe it's appropriate for you to count it as a square, maybe it isn't. That's up to your application. But $0=\sqrt2\times 0$, so it's a matter of fact that the "diagonal" is $\sqrt2$ times the "side".

Comment: $0$ is absolutely a length. How long is the longest train track on the moon?

Comment: In general I would say 0 is a length, but mathematically it is not a distance. 2 points directly on top of each other don't have a distance between them, e.g. you can't draw a vector between them. If you can't draw a vector between them can you define an angle or length?

Answer (score 1):

Most, if not all, authors require that a $n$-gon has exactly $n$ distinct vertices.

Comment: Do you have some, um. ELI5 sources for some of these authors? I've looked in Google Scholar and I'm out of my league trying to understand it. and what mathematically defines a vertice?